# Clone object in LUA

Tags: lua

I have the next code and I'm trying to create a copy of the object Test:

```
local Test = {} do
    local var1, var2 = {}

    function Test:Init(val1, val2, val3)
        var1.val1 = val1
        var1.val2 = val2
        var1.val3 = val3
    end

    function Test:Print()
        print(var1.val1)
        print(var1.val2)
        print(var1.val3)
    end

    function Test:New(obj)
        obj = obj or {}
        setmetatable(obj, self)
        self.__index = self
        return obj
    end
end
```

Then I'm creating my objects like this:

```
local obj1 = Test:New()
obj1:Init('a','b','c')
local obj2 = Test:New()
obj2:Init('c','d','e')

obj1:Print()
obj2:Print()
```

The result will be this:

```
c, d, e
c, d, e
```

As you can see the method `New` is not cloning correctly the object and is sharing the same instance. What am I doing wrong? I haven't cloned an object before and I'm having issues to understand how to do it.
I got that code from here: https://www.lua.org/pil/16.2.html

Thanks.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `local var1, var2` declaration? The only solution I see is to remove that and make your code more similar to what's in the text.

Comment: You were right, I had to declarate the variables with `self.` instead of local variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because you are just changing local variables, not the object itself.

When you do `local Test = {} do` you are not doing too much about the `Test` object, you are just creating the table and then creating a new scope which will be executed immediately, and inside this scope you have the variable `var1`, which will be shared through the scope, not the object.

The correct way to implement variables for each is actually creating fields on it:

```
local Test = {} do    
    function Test:Init(val1, val2, val3)
        self.val1 = val1
        self.val2 = val2
        self.val3 = val3
    end

    function Test:Print()
        print(self.val1)
        print(self.val2)
        print(self.val3)
    end

    function Test:New(obj)
        obj = obj or {}
        setmetatable(obj, self)
        self.__index = self
        return obj
    end
end
```

Anyway `setmetatable` it's not about cloning objects, it implement shared behaviors and then you can create as many objects you want with those behaviors.